# Is Bamako Mali airport safe?

Tags: layovers, mali

I am considering a Turkish Airlines flight with 55 minute layover in Bamako Mali. Travel to Mali is highly discouraged by various safety advisors due to the security situation. Is the airport secure enough to make this flight a reasonable plan?

Comment: I don't think you would even be getting off the plane.  Turkish wouldn't fly to Bamako if their planes were not secure while on the ground.  I expect there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Airports are usually very secure spaces in most parts of the world because of their strategic importance. At the same time, they are also the first places to be attacked during an insurgency because of the same reason. So it's a double edged sword, but as mentioned by @phoog Turkish Airlines won't fly there if it was unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Airports do get attacked sometimes but this is the case for serious uprisings and terrorism, not usually criminality such as theft and assault since airports have permanent armed security. Even in a peaceful countries like Iceland where the police is unarmed, airport security is.

Mali is known to have safety issues but you should be relatively safe in the airport. Generally though, I try to avoid passing through similar regions in case there is an issue, forcing to stay overnight outside of the airport in an dangerous and unknown location. The risk is fairly low, specially it is the same flight going to the next destination, you are unlikely to face an issue unless there is a mechanical failure.